# How to avoid the lexical redundancy in the literal Spanish translation of "to ask a question"?

Tags: traducción, preguntas

In English we have different words for the verb *to ask* and the noun *question*.

But in Spanish *to ask* is *preguntar* and *question* is *pregunta*.

This always causes me to stumble when speaking Spanish and I come to say something I would phrase in English as *to ask a question*. Because saying *preguntar una pregunta* sounds definitely wrong.

In Spanish would I substitute a synonym for *preguntar* or for *pregunta* or would I have to recast each sentence on a case by case basis?

---

Of course there are other senses of *preguntar* and *pregunta* and other words for other senses of *to ask* and *question*, but they're not relevant to this question. You *cannot* say:

- preguntar un cuestión (literally "ask a matter")
- pedir una pregunta (literally "request a question")

Indeed you can often avoid needing both a verb and its object but sometimes its either not avoidable or requires changing the sentence completely (randomly googled examples):

- Have interview questions of your own ready to ask.
- Interview Questions to Ask the Employer
- Most Commonly Asked Sawfish Questions
- Frequently Asked Antitrust Questions
- when asking or answering questions ...
- ... they ask themselves two questions.
- The better question to ask is how many young people refuse to use the ...
- How To Ask Basic Questions Using Sign Language
- Both asking and answering questions are important parts of effective learning and teaching.

Comment: I'm just here to add that "question" doesn't always translate as «pregunta»; when you want to discuss an issue or controversy rather than just an interrogative, you need «cuestión». The next time you're discussing the Schleswig-Holstein Question, it's what you want. And Spanish for "ask" is usually «pedir», unless all you want is the answer to a question, so the English equivalent for «preguntar» really requires both "ask" and "question." Oh, and "to question" is «interrogar». It's like a tar pit for anybody who wants to translate word-by-word.

Comment: @Brian yeah I didn't want to go into all of that stuff because they are separate senses and might confuse or distract some readers.

Comment: Yes, it's redundant indeed, however, some people like me don't care about redundancy. There is not much virtue in finding a synonym to avoid making a sentence with words too similar. However, the answer highly voted, I like it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*To ask a question* is **Hacer una pregunta**. Some examples:

> - *Él me hizo una pregunta.* (= He asked me a question.) And also: "Él me preguntó".
> - *Déjame hacerte una pregunta.* (= Let me ask you a question.)

*Preguntar una pregunta* does sound wrong to me as well; it's redundant. You only need to say it once, for example:

> *Pregúntame lo que quieres.* (= Ask me whatever you want.)

This example, though correct grammatically, doesn't sound right, a Spanish speaker won't use this form. It would be either "Pregúntame lo que quier**a**s" or "**Dime** lo que quieres".

You've given some interesting examples in your question. Next to each one is how I would handle it in general terms. Others may tackle them differently:

> - *Prepare sus propias preguntas de entrevista.* In Castilian Spanish the correct form is *Prepare sus propias preguntas **para la** entrevista.*
>     (Have interview questions of your own ready to ask.)
> - *Preguntas de entrevista para hacer al empleador.* Ditto: *Preguntas para hacer durante la entrevista a la empresa*
>     (Interview questions to ask the employer.)
> - *(Las) preguntas más comúnes sobre el Pez Sierra.*
>     (Most commonly asked sawfish questions.)
> - Frequently Asked Antitrust Questions.
>     (same idea, but I'd use *frecuentes* instead of *comunes*, naturally.)
> - *Haciendo o respondiendo preguntas* OR *cuando preguntas se hagan o respondan*
>     (when asking or answering questions.)
> - *Ellos se hacen dos preguntas.*
>     (they ask themselves two questions.)
> - *La mejor pregunta para hacer es cuántos jóvenes negan usar el/la ...* Ditto: *La pregunta más apropiada es cuántos jóvenes **se** n**i**egan **a** usar el/la ...*
>     (The better question to ask is how many young people refuse to
>     use the ... )
> - *Cómo hacer preguntas básicas con el lenguaje por señas.*
>     (How to ask basic questions using sign language.)
> - *Hacer y responder preguntas, las dos son partes importantes de aprendizaje efectivo y enseñanza efectiva.* Ditto:  *Preguntar y responder, ambas son partes importantes de un aprendizaje y enseñanza efectivos.*
>     (Both asking and answering questions are important parts of effective learning and teaching.)

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. I edited my question with a bunch of examples where the second way doesn't work so easily.

Comment: I expanded on ay answer with what I would do in those situations. Most use the straightforward `hacer una pregunta` and `responder una pregunta` constructs.

Comment: I'm going to delete the parts on translating "ask a matter" and "request a question" from this otherwise excellent answer because those don't even make sense in English. They were not translation problems like the others but illustrations of how word-for-word translations often don't work.

Comment: Wow, did I really write this answer? Blast from the past. In any case, no issues with the edit.

Comment: Why does pregúntame have an accent added?

Comment: @Stormblessed The stress is on the second syllable from the last (antepenultimate). Spelling rules dictate that an access is always placed in this case. Other examples: pájaro, énfasis.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede:

- Formular una pregunta
- Hacer una pregunta
- Indagar por algo
- Averiguar por
- Preguntar acerca de

Comment: Podrías aplicar esas fórmulas a los ejemplos de la pregunta para mostrar cómo se evitaría el "ask a question"? La repuesta de Kevin recoge "hacer una pregunta" y  "formular una pregunta" es muy similar, pero aplicar las otras fórmulas que propones a los "randomly googled examples" de la pregunta es no trivial. No se ve bien cómo sustituir o aplicar _"Averiguar por"_ para "they **ask** themselves two **questions**" o "Both asking and answering questions are important parts [...]". Creo que esta pregunta debería ampliarse un poco más...