# How would you say "The question asks"?

Tags: preguntas

Along the same vein as [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/737/how-to-avoid-the-lexical-redundancy-in-the-literal-spanish-translation-of-to-as), how would you say "The question asks...?"

For example, "What does the question ask?" or "The question asks that you divide X by Y"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how we'd normally say in Colombia, I wouldn't be able to tell for sure that it applies to other countries as well, but it works for us.

> What does the question ask? = ¿Qué te pide la pregunta? ¿Qué tienes que hacer?
>
> The question asks that you divide X by Y = La pregunta dice que debes dividir X entre Y / La pregunta te pide que dividas X entre Y.

Comment: Same here in Spain :)

Comment: Creo que una traducción válida en España también sería:
¿Cuál es la pregunta?
Esto intenta indicar que has escuchado la pregunta, pero no entiendes bien a qué exactamente tienes que responder. Se suele usar cuando la pregunta es un poco ambigua.

Comment: Qué **se** pide...

Answer (score 0):

**What does the question ask? = ¿Qué pide la pregunta?** (Here we use **ask** for **pedir,** since sometimes we introduce it to say **pregunta.** — e.g. **don't ask = no preguntes.**)

---

Now, it's not that simple as it looks:

— *The question ask that you divide X by Y = La pregunta pide que **dividas** X por Y.*

It's uses the subjunctive, not terribly complex but it's often translated as shown before. Now, as a side note, we don't make any distinction by saying — *La pregunta pide que dividas X por Y / X entre Y* —

In Spanish language we often omit the pronouns, we don't say them everytime we speak. In light of this, we can rephrase the sentence as — *La pregunta pide que* (*tú*) *dividas* (...) —

Comment: I think it should be `Qué se pide la pregunta`.  It's more passive, just like the English sentence.

Comment: No, you don't use **se** in that sentence. If you want to, we require the particle **de**. — *¿Qué se pide de la pregunta?* —

Comment: I agree with @Oshnaj. *¿Qué se pide la pregunta?* doesn't make sense. And even *¿Qué se pide de la pregunta?* sounds awkward to me. *¿Qué pide la pregunta?* or *¿Qué te pide la pregunta?* are just fine.