# ¿Puedo hacerte una pregunta?

Tags: sintaxis

I know this means, Can I ask you a question, but why.
Puedo - Can i
Hacerte = make you
Una pregunta - a question.

So this really translates to = Can I make you a question?
Why is it read - Can I ask you a question?

Answer (score 4):

Because in Spanish "ask a question" is "preguntar una pregunta" and this is a redundancy. Saying "preguntar una pregunta" is not wrong but it is not the most appropriate way. Instead: hacer una pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Las traducciones no son siempre automáticas y los verbos empleados en un idioma no sirven para otro, pues dependen de su especificidad y de sus distintas acepciones.

> Translations are not always automatic and the verbs used in one
> language are not useful for another, since they depend on their
> specificity and their different meanings.

"make" es un verbo mejor orientado para aspectos relacionados con "construct, build, manufacture, produce, create..." y el verbo "ask" para preguntar.

> "make" is a better oriented verb for aspects related to "construct,
> build, manufacture, produce, create..." and the "ask" verb to ask.

En español, no suena muy bien ¿Puedo preguntar una pregunta? es como si en inglés dijera ¿puedo cuestionar una cuestión?, por eso normalmente se utiliza el verbo "hacer" en el sentido de crear, realizar, fabricar... una cuestión.

> In Spanish, it doesn't sound very good. Can (Puedo) I ask (preguntar)
> a (una) question (pregunta)? It is as if in English it said, can I
> question a question? That is why the verb "hacer" is normally used in
> the sense of creating, carrying out, fabricate... a question.

Otras Cuestiones // Another Questions

El verbo "hacer" como transitivo, significa, básicamente, 'producir o fabricar' y 'realizar o ejecutar'; como pronominal, 'convertirse en algo o llegar a ser algo' (Se hizo médico) y 'fingir ser algo' (Se hizo el muerto); como intransitivo no pronominal, con un complemento con de, 'representar un papel' (En la obra hacía de reina) y

https://www.rae.es/dpd/hacer

> The verb "**hacer**" as a transitive means, basically, 'to produce or
> manufacture' and 'to carry out or execute'; as a pronominal, 'to
> become something or become something' (He became a doctor) and 'to
> pretend to be something' (He played dead); as a non-pronominal
> intransitive, with a complement with de, 'play a role' (in the play
> she played the queen)...

https://www.rae.es/dpd/hacer

De manera habitual, en español, el verbo **PODER** se utiliza para pedir favores  y **hacer peticiones** o solicitudes a otras personas.

> Normally, in Spanish, the verb **PODER** is used to ask for favors and
> **make requests** or requests to other people.

Si aún te es difícil entenderlo, tienes la posibilidad de traducirlo como una oración más formal e igualmente válida;

- **¿Puedo preguntar una cuestión?**
- **¡Tengo una cuestión!**
- **¡Tengo una pregunta!**
- **¿Puedo preguntar?**

> If it is still difficult for you to understand it, you have the
> possibility of translating it into a more formal and equally valid
> sentence.
>
> **Can I ask a question?**
>
> **I have a question!**
>
> **Can I ask?**

La formula, ¿ Puedo hacer una pregunta?, es las más informal que vendría más o menos a decir.

(¿Puedo crear una pregunta para  ti?), (¿Puedo enunciar una pregunta para  ti?)

> The formula, Can I ask a question?, is the most informal that would more or less
> come to say.
>
> (Can I create a question for you?), (Can I state a question for you?)

---

**P.D.** Buscando, encontré esta cuestión de hace diez años y que puede ser interesante.

> Searching, I found this question from ten years ago and it may be
> interesting.

¿Cómo evitar la redundancia léxica en la traducción literal al español de "to ask a question"?

> How to avoid he lexical redundancy in the literal Spanish translation
> of "to ask a question"?

[How to avoid the lexical redundancy in the literal Spanish translation of "to ask a question"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/737/how-to-avoid-the-lexical-redundancy-in-the-literal-spanish-translation-of-to-as)

Comment: There is no lexical redundancy. ask a question=hacer una pregunta. Do you have to be a trained translator to know that? For age: tener x años, English: to be x years old.

Comment: Hola Lambie, en español si dices " ¿puedo preguntar una pregunta?" es redundante y posee cacofonía sonora o acústica que resulta desagradable a quien lo escucha. Tengas un día agradable. Cuando hablo de redundancia, me refiero a eso.

Comment: Pero Diego, la traducción correcta de: May I ask you a question es idiomaticamente Te puedo **hacer** una pregunta. La única redundancia vendría de una mala traducción del inglés y no del español. De ninguna manera.

Comment: Hola lambie. May I ask you a question?, ¿Te puedo hacer una pregunta?. Es solo un invento, una forma de adaptar, ¿Puedo yo preguntarte una cuestión?, a la sonoridad de otro idioma para entender un significado. Normalmente basta con decir "¿Puedo preguntar?",  "Pregúntale" "Ronda de preguntas".. en lugar de hazle una pregunta. Es obvio que también se utiliza ¿Te puedo hacer una pregunta?,  pero en contextos más personales e íntimos que requieren cierta sinceridad y si atendemos a la economía del lenguaje, esto realmente no funciona. La 1ª traducción que se hizo acabo por quedarse. ¡Cuídate!

Comment: En Español "May I ask you a question? ¿Puedo preguntar una cuestión?" suena muy pomposo por lo que tuvieron que adaptar la información a otro rango sonoro más acorde, realmente tenían que cambiar la palabra "cuestión", "question", por otra. La verdad no pensaron mucho y acudieron a la definición que da el diccionario del verbo preguntar. Preguntar. ‘Hacer preguntas o pedir información a alguien sobre un asunto’. De aquí quitaron "question" y añadieron la definición que habían hallado de Preguntar  = hacer preguntas y voilà! ¿Te puedo hacer una pregunta?. ¿Te puedo preguntar-te-le....?

Comment: Todavia no me has entendido. ESTO: ¿Puedo preguntar una cuestión?" no es español. No se dice. No has estudiado la traducción, ¿verdad? No vale la pena intentar convencer una persona que no quiere escuchar lo óbvio.... Es como decir: Cuantos anõs  es? En vez de tienes.

Comment: @lambie. obvio, How old are you?. ¿Cuál es tu edad?. Quot annos nata es. ¿Puedo preguntar una cuestión? si es español. La gente, normalmente cuando va al médico dice, Señor doctor, me duele la espalda. Los menos dicen, Señor doctor me duele el coxis. Ambas fórmulas son correctas, aunque solo una minoría elige utilizar la opción más culta.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple:
the idiomatic usage: to **ask someone a question**, in English
in Spanish is: **hacer una pregunta** a alguien.

In Spanish, they use make, in English we use ask.

That is just the way it is.

For someone's age it's the same thing. We say to **be some number of years**, and in Spanish *they have (tener) to have some number of years*.

You just have to learn these things and literal translation will almost never be of any use.

Comment: We can, of course, pose a question to someone although it is much less common.

Comment: @mdewey There are many ways to say things. My main point is that in the question "Can I ask you a question" the verb in Spanish is hacer. And that is what constitutes being idiomatic which the OP is apparently not aware of.